# How to invoke std stream operator from within templated stream operator?

Tags: c++, templates, iostream

I have a number of vector classes for which I'd like to implement a generic stream operator like this:

```
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const T& v)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < T::num_elems; ++i)
    {
        os << " " << v.a[i];
    }
    return os;
}
```

This almost works, except that I get an error for `os << " " << ...` of course, because it's ambiguous. How can I disambiguate this and force the `<<` operator from `std::` to be used here ?

Alternatively, how can I restrict the use of this templated stream operator to just my vector classes ? I've put the vector classes and the stream operator into a separate namespace but that doesn't seem to be enough.

The start of the actual error message:

```
foo.cpp:73: error: ambiguous overload for 'operator<<' in 'os << " "'
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ostream:169:0 /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ostream:169: note: candidates are: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>] <near match>
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ostream:177:0 /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ostream:177: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(long unsigned int) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>] <near match>
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ostream:185:0 /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ostream:185: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(bool) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
...
```

Some further clarification: the stream operator is only being used in a test harness (UnitTest++), it's not part of a public API. Also the vector classes are small custom fixed size vectors (really just simple arrays), not C++ vectors.

A stripped down example of one of the vector classes that I need this to work with:

```
struct VectorClass {
    enum { num_elems = 16 };
    int32_t a[num_elems];
};
```

Comment: it will likely always be ambiguous for most standard libraries, as they surely use templates at certain places too.

Comment: @DyP: thanks - could you expand on how I'd use a qualified-id here exactly ?

Comment: This is a **dangerous** function declaration, since it claims to be used for `os << ANYTHING`.

Comment: @Drew: OK - so how would I restrict its use to just my vector classes ?

Comment: `os.operator<<(v.a[i]);` (it's not a qualified-id, but should work IIRC), but Drew Dormann is right.

Comment: @stardust_: the type of `v.a[i]` is just a simple integer or floating point POD type - the exact type depends on the vector class.

Comment: IIRC you can restrict your function template using SFINAE (or like Drew Dormann pointed out in his answer), that could also help resolving your ambiguity.

Comment: Can you give an example of what those vector classes look like

Comment: @Bart: I'll try and condense one of the vector classes down into a simple example and add it to the question shortly.

Comment: @PaulR your example `VectorClass` class doesn't need a `template` function.  The problem we're trying to solve is "How are all the types similar?"  That can't be solved with one example type.

Comment: "one of those vector classes" so how do the others look like?

Comment: @DyP: there are around 20 similar classes, with different POD types and array sizes, but otherwise the same. I was hoping to just implement one stream operator that would work for all these classes. UnitTest++ requires this and several other operators so that it can  report details of test failures etc.

Comment: Can you put all your vector classes in one namespace? If so, you could make use of argument-dependent name lookup IIRC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, you can use SFINAE (like in Drew Dormann's answer) or argument-dependent name     lookup using namespaces:

```
namespace all_my_vectors
{
    struct myVector1 { int a; };
    struct myVector2 { int a; };

    template < typename Vector >
    std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, Vector const& v)
    {
        o << v.a; // look up name in std::ostream, namespace std, global namespace, namespace of v.a
        return o;
    }
}

int main()            
{
    all_my_vectors::myVector1 v1;
    all_my_vectors::myVector2 v2;

    std::cout << v1 << v2; // look up name in std::ostream, namespace std, global namespace, namespace all_my_vectors

    return 0;
}
```

Edit: If they share a common base class, you should use stardust_'s approach.

Answer (score 3):

> there are around 20 similar classes, with different POD types and array sizes, but otherwise the same.

Create a named function that does the generalized work.

```
template <typename T>
std::ostream& SendVectorToOstream(std::ostream& os, const T& v)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < T::num_elems; ++i)
    {
        os << " " << v.a[i];
    }
    return os;
}
```

Now you can have your `operator<<` functions forward to it.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const VectorClassA & v)
{
    return SendVectorToOstream( os, v );
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const VectorClassB & v)
{
    return SendVectorToOstream( os, v );
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const VectorClassC & v)
{
    return SendVectorToOstream( os, v );
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I should have been clearer in my question: (a) the stream operator is only being used in a test harness (UnitTest++), it's not part of a public API and (b) the vector classes are small custom fixed size vectors (really just simple arrays), not C++ vectors.

Comment: @PaulR Sorry - I can't improve on this answer without knowing the type to replace `std::vector<T>` with.

Comment: Thanks - I'll add an example to the question shortly.

Comment: Thanks for the update - this still requires one stream operator per class though (although they are simpler now)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking the wrong way. Template is not the solution. What you want is Inheritance. Something like this

```
template< typename T>
struct VectorClass {


    enum { num_elems = 4 };
    T* a;

};


template< typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const VectorClass<T>& v)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VectorClass<T>::num_elems; ++i)
        {
            os << " " << v.a[i];
        }
        return os;
    }


template< typename T>
class DerivedClass : public VectorClass<T> {

};




int main(){

    DerivedClass<int> v;

    int* tmp = new int[VectorClass<int>::num_elems];

    for (int i = 0; i < VectorClass<int>::num_elems; ++i) {
        tmp[i] = i;
    }

    v.a = tmp;

    cout << v;

}
```

Comment: Doing it this way would mean having the same stream operator in all classes.

Comment: If they derive from Vectorclass then they don't have to define it.

Comment: @stardust_ No reason to make it a friend function; it accesses no private members of `VectorClass`.

Comment: @Billy ONeal Not here. But I think in his actuall code it will. Just to be safe.

Comment: @stardust_: Making something `friend` induces a *lack* of safety. I mention this because there seems to be a misconception that operator overloads must be friends or members.

Comment: I just tried using inheritance, but the problem is that the member variable declarations all need to be in the subclasses (since they are all different) and so you can't define a generic stream operator in the parent class.

Comment: Unfortunately the type of `a` depends on the class - it can be one of several different integer types, or float/double.

Comment: Yes of course. If you want to print differently for each class then you need different overloads for each. I don't understand here. What exactly do you want to be printed? isn't it a common thing for all VectorClass related classes?

Comment: then make the class template. What you need to make sure is the type used by the class template has << overloaded. If it is simple types like int and string then it is OK. Otherwise it has << overloaded.

Comment: Thanks - that looks like it would almost work - some of the classes have the same `T` though, but they have different num_elems, so it might be possible to add a second template parameter for this.

Answer (score 1):

If all of your vector classes have a common attribute, such as `num_elems`, you can implement this using [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error).

```
template <typename T,          size_t SFINAE = T::num_elems >
// The only difference is here ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const T& v)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < T::num_elems; ++i)
    {
        os << " " << v.a[i];
    }
    return os;
}
```

This change forces this `ostream <<` to only apply to types `T` that define a `T::num_elems` that can be converted to `size_t`, like your enum.

*This solution assumes a C++11 compiler.*

Comment: Note that this requires default values for function templates, a C++11 feature. Note also that this allows someone to specify the SFIANE parameter explicitly, which is probably undesired.

Comment: @BillyONeal You mean if someone called the function as `operator << < Vector, 42 >( os, v )` instead of `os << v`?  That's inconsequential to the function's behavior.  Although someone should probably have a talk with the author.  :)